# mysql why getting different result with count and sort function on same table column?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I'm using phpMyAdmin.

I have a Table_a

The first column is:

```
join_id  big_int(20)  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT
```

My COUNT query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(join_id)
FROM table_a
WHERE join_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Result is:

```
COUNT(join_id) 1894275
```

My SELECT (ascending) query is:

```
SELECT join_id 
FROM `table_a` 
ORDER BY join_id ASC;
```

Result is:

```
join_id
1
2
3
:
1924724
```

My SELECT (descending) query is:

```
SELECT join_id 
FROM `table_a` 
ORDER BY join_id DESC;
```

Result is:

```
join_id
1926573
1926572
1926571
:
1850
```

COUNT and SELECT give me different result (they should be the same)?

And I get a different result in the SELECT statement if use ascending versus descending?

```
COUNT = 1894275
SELECT (ascending) = 1 to 1924724
SELECT (descending = 1926573 to 1850
```

If I modify the two SELECT statements to include a WHERE IS NOT NULL e.g.:

```
SELECT join_id 
FROM `table_a` 
WHERE join_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY join_id ASC;
```

I get a consistent result e.g.:

```
join_id (ascending SELECT query)
1
2
3
:
1926573
```

and

```
join_id (descending SELECT query)
1926573
1926572
1926571
:
1
```

1. What could be causing the COUNT and SELECT statements to generate different results on an auto-increment field?
2. Why do I need IS NOT NULL to get a consistent result when using the SELECT statements? I have up until now assumed NOT to be implicit in an AUTO_INCREMENT field.

The query

```
SELECT join_id 
FROM `table_a` 
WHERE join_id IS NULL
```

returns no results (as expected)
Thanks!

Comment: Deleted records would create "gaps" in the auto increment; these would show up in the `SELECT` statements, while `COUNT` would ignore these and only return the real total row count, not the final auto increment value

Comment: Doh! of course. It is a newly created table so was thinking id's consistent. But now obvious...I did have to modify an INSERT part way through populating the table which would have affected the id's. Not surprisingly (now)  the modification was on about the same no's of rows as gap...